# alternating .setFontSize() inside of an array

Tags: javascript

Im not really a programmer so please excuse the slightly crude description. This is an expression for a textlayer in Adobe After Effects (which uses Javascript)

I currently use this expression to generate an array of values (which is later used as customizable labels for the axes of a graph)

```
x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list)
y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps)
z= 5 //the number of steps

Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x + "km").join("\n")
```

which outputs

```
0km
20km
40km
60km
80km
```

Then I thought it would also be good to have miles in there so I changed the code to this

```
Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x + "km " + (i * y + x) * 0.6 +"mi").join("\n")
```

I suppose its not beautiful but it does the job ...

```
0km 0mi
20km 12mi
40km 24mi
60km 36mi
80km 48mi
```

I then tried to add a customizable fontsize. Thats how I did it.

```
text.sourceText.style.setText
(
Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x + "km " + (i * y + x) * 0.6 +"mi").join("\n")
)
.setFontSize(20)
```

This worked, but really I only want a different font size for the miles value and this is where I ran into trouble. I tried

```
Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x + "km " + text.sourceText.style.setText((i * y + x) * 0.6 +"mi").setFontSize(10)).join("\n")
```

but this seems to break the code. It only outputs

```
0km [object Object]
20km [object Object]
40km [object Object]
60km [object Object]
80km [object Object]
```

any ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: `.setText()` and `.setFontSize()` both seem to be methods you can call on `text.sourceText.style` - I think you have to make two text objects, one for km and one for mi, to be able to set the font size seperately

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought too. But since I dont know how to write code (I usually just copy and paste stuff together till it works) I dont understand how to do that.
I tried something like this to seperate mi and km 

Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x + "km ") + Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => (i * y + x)*0.6 + "mi ").join("\n")

but its obvious even to me why this doesnt work

Comment: I guess you have to have two times `text.sourceText.style.setText().setFontSize()`